# Entity Framework 6.1.1 [NotMapped] attribute not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a NuGet package that contains a `DbContext` with all the models. Within another project we installed this NuGet package.

Let's say we have the following model in the source code of the NuGet package:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Mode Mode { get; set; }
}
```

In the main project, where the `DbContext` is not a reference to the NuGet package but simply a project reference, it works as expected. However in the project that uses the NuGet package we always have the following exception:

```
Invalid column name 'Mode'.
```

It does not make sense as `[NotMapped]` is correctly used. I also made sure that the `NotMapped` attribute is coming from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace.

Also, it used to work fine, but we added a column to one of our models recently and updated the NuGet package and since then we have this issue.

Comment: Mode is a navigation property anyways... what is the query you are trying to run?

Comment: A very simple query, like `context.Set<Account>().Find(id);`. I found a workaround, creating a new DbContext that inherits from the one in the NuGet package and overriding the `OnModelCreating` method to explicitly ignore the columns in errors... Also in my case `Mode` is an enum.